# Byte unary operation

Tags: java

We all know that in Java these operators:

```
a++;
++a;
a += 1;
a = a + 1;
```

do the same thing, they simply add 1 to variable 'a'

However why these statements are not all true, what is the principle behind this?

```
byte a = 1;
a++;
++a;
a += 1;
a = a + 1; // This line will result to a compile time error
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you perform a binary operation between two operands of different types, one of the operands is promoted to the higher type. And then the result of the operation is of that type.

So, in your case, the `byte` type `a` is first promoted to an `int`, since `1` is an `int` type. And then after the addition operation, the result is of type `int`. Now, since you cannot assign an `int` to a `byte`, you need to do a typecast to remove the compiler error:

```
byte a = 2;
a = a + 1;   // Error: Cannot assign an int value to byte
a = (byte)(a + 1);  // OK
```

---

Now, in case of *Compound Assignment Operator*, the typecasting is done implicitly for you. The expression:

```
a += 1
```

is internally converted to:

```
a = (byte)(a + 1);
```

This is specified in JLS - [§15.26.2 Compound Assignment Operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1 is evaluated only once.

Similar is the case with *prefix increment operators*, and *postfix increment operators*.
According to JLS - [§15.15 Unary Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15):

> The type of the prefix increment expression is the type of the variable.

Comment: Side note: It's not only widening conversion because `a = a + (byte)1` doesn't work either. It's also the fact that integer arithmetic operations are always done on either `int` or `long`. You *always* have to cast the result if you're using smaller types.

Comment: @Joey. Yeah the result of any binary operation has always the type at least as `int`.

Comment: You mean that Java arithmetic operators assume that all operands are of 'int' or 'long' type?

Comment: @Chalk_dusT Not assume , converted to `int` or `long`, as per JLS 5.6.2.

Comment: @cHaLk_dusT. No it's not like that. If both the operands are of type smaller than `int`, even then both of them would be promoted to an `int`.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot, Rohit Jain, okay I got it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**a = a + 1;**

That is due to type of the expression `a = a + 1;` . The LHS is promoted to `int` and then the addition is performed. You are then trying to assign the `int` value back to a `byte` without casting .

Refer the [JLS 5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)

> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> 1. If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
> 2. Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
> 3. Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
> 4. Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.

**a++;
++a;**

Here the type is that of the type of the variable. Again as per the [JLS 15.15](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15)

> The type of the prefix increment expression is the type of the variable.
>
> The type of the prefix decrement expression is the type of the variable.

**a += 1;**

As per the [JLS 15.26.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2)

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1 is evaluated only once.

Hence here `a += 1;` is equivalent to `a = (byte)(a+1);`, as it is done implicitly .

Comment: Based on the Java Tutorials : Assignment, Arithmetic, and Unary Operators, it is stated that both these lines x+=1; and x=x+1 are both compound assignments